# 'Randomizing' Gradient method for the proposal of Metro-Hastings step

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

In my problem, I've used a gradient method for the mean of the proposal.

Let my proposal be $q(\mu_n,\Sigma)$, where $\mu_n = \mu_{n-1}+s\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log(f(y,\theta))$ and $s$ is the step magnitude.

However, every once in a while, due to machine-precision considerations, the gradient cannot be computed, i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log(f(y,\theta))$ is not computationally obtainable because several in-built functions cannot handle some of the values, and the general algorithm simple stops.

So, instead of just using the gradient method, I've decided to use the following

> The mean of the proposal is
>
> - Gradient if it's computationally possible: $\mu_n = \mu_{n-1}+s\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\log(f(y,\theta))$
> - When gradient is not available, just draw from a uniform distribution:$\mu_n = \mu_{n-1}+ s x$, where $x\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$

Is this way of computing the mean for the proposal formally valid?

From the simulations I've done, the results seem to be better than if I just use a RW for the proposal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Spontaneously, what makes it a little bit difficult is that you do the second proposal only when the first is not computationally possible. That sounds like a tricky random variable to condition on... Otherwise, there are similarities with adaptive MH (although obviously different). What saves you there is I believe that you have a positive probability to make a proposal using a fixed proposal variance. (I'm not sure this is helpful at all, it's just something your post made me think of.)

Comment: [i searched around and this was the first thing that popped up](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.00095.pdf)